# Uniform Convergence on exponential function.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

The question:

Let $f_{n}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of functions  which $f_{n} (x) = \exp[-nx^2]$. Determine whether or not this sequence converges uniformly.

The attempt:

I drew some pictures of these types of functions and I am claiming the sequence of functions do not converge uniformly. I am provided that this sequence converges point-wise to $0$ if $x \neq 0$ and to $1$ if $x = 0$. 
I am using the $\epsilon-N$ definition of uniform convergence.

Let's look at the case when $x \neq 0$ (This is my scratch work). We choose $\epsilon = 1/2$. Then, for all $N \geq 1$,we need to find a $n \geq N$ and an $x \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $| \exp[-nx^2]| \geq \frac{1}{2}$. Since the function is positive, we need to find an $n$ and an $x$ such that $\exp[-nx^2] \geq \frac{1}{2}$. The problem I am having is the algebra. Am I on track or not?

Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

> **To answer the question in the OP, yes, you are on track.**

For $\epsilon=1/2$, simply take any $n\ge 1$ and take $x=\sqrt{\log(2)/n}$.

Can you now conclude that the sequence fails to converge uniformly on $[0, \infty)$?

Comment: Well in your hint, do we have to consider the negative root of x ?

Comment: No.  The $\sqrt n$ is positive for $n\ge 1$

Comment: No I completely understand it. Thank you very much!!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

The pointwise limit function is not continuous, so the convergence is not uniform.

Of course, if $(f_n)$ converges uniformly, then the uniform limit function is a pointwise limit as well. Then it is enough to investigate theproperties of a pointwise limit.

Comment: Okay. Why is it that if the point wise limit $f(x)$ is continuous, then the sequence is uniformly convergent?

Comment: @overachiever That's not correct.  If it uniformly converges, the the limit function of a sequence of continous functions is continuous.  The logic does not go the other way.  But if the limit function is discontinuous, then the sequence cannot converge uniformly.